# Assigning json response value to a textview

Tags: android, json

I'm getting data from json response to use in my application. Json response is responding a value which is belongs to Type C. and I have taken the value to the variable `extraCheese`. Now I want to assign the value of `extraCheese` to the `extraCheseChTV` text view. `extraCheese` is having only one value that is why I'm trying to assign it to a textview. 
How is it possible to do.

```
    private TextView extraCheseChTV;

    List<String> extraCheese = new ArrayList<String>();

    if ((objectE.getString("Description")) != null
       && (objectE.getString("Type")).equals("C")) {

    extraCheese.add(objectE.getString("Description"));
  }
```

I tried to do that by doing,

`extraCheseChTV.setText(extraCheese);` but it gave me an error because I have assigned `extraCheese`  as `List<String>`.

Comment: try extraCheseChTV.setText(extraCheese[0]);

Comment: @Prag's シ it gave me this exception, The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to List<String>

Comment: it was just example.. u should try.. `extraCheese.get(0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
extraCheseChTV.setText(extraCheese.get(0));
```

to get value from list, always use list_name.get(position);

Comment: system crashed and it gave this exception 03-10 09:52:54.950: E/AndroidRuntime(22633): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: means your **if** condition is not satisfied, so that list is not getting value, plz check response from web service carefully

Answer (score 0):

extraCheese is a list of Strings. You would need to retrieve the value of the list first.

Try it like this:

```
extraCheeseTV.setText(extraCheese.get(0));
```

Also if you only have one value consider not using a list, but simply a String.

Comment: system crashed and it gave this exception 03-10 09:52:54.950: E/AndroidRuntime(22633): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0